# Why doesn't this loop run properly?

Tags: python, loops, pygame, exit

```
while g.running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            g.running = False
    g.run(Player_1)

quit()
```

when I run this loop it completely skips the for loop or just does it once and is too fast for me to be able to run and it just goes on to run. How do I make the loop work fine?
https://github.com/maartenww/100daysOfCode_projectOne << for the full code.

Also, what g.run basically does is just update the game. So it draws and or moves all the sprites, draws the text unto the screen and does some calculations

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True

    def run(self, player_1):
        self.border_col(player_1)
        self.load_text(player_1)
        self.update_game(player_1)

    def update_game(self, player_1):
        clock.tick(FPS)
        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        gameDisplay.blit(self.xcolon, (0, 0))
        gameDisplay.blit(self.actual_x, (25, 0))
        gameDisplay.blit(self.ycolon, (0, 30))
        gameDisplay.blit(self.actual_y, (25, 30))
        gameDisplay.blit(self.acolon, (0, 60))
        gameDisplay.blit(self.actual_a, (25, 60))
        gameDisplay.blit(self.vcolon, (0, 90))
        gameDisplay.blit(self.actual_v, (25, 90))
        all_sprites.draw(gameDisplay)
        Player.move_player(player_1)
        Player.update_player(player_1)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down to a smaller reproducible example?

Comment: @doctorlove how do you mean?

Comment: As it stands, the code you have posted doesn't tell me what `g` is. Of course, some people can go read you github code. But then the question isn't self contained. If you change the code on github this question won't make sense to people in the future. Can you include a skimmed down version of your `Game` class that exhibits the same behaviour?

Comment: And another question - which events are you expecting? Does the `g.run` line get called over and over, but you only get one event (at most)? Or are you saying it drops through to `quit`?

Comment: @doctorlove ah now I understand, sure

Comment: @doctorlove I accidentally still had 'print ('f')' because debugging :P 
I changed it now though. And what it basically does is as soon as you do quit (aka press 'x' of the window) the loop will end and the program goes to quit

Comment: Please don't post links to your files, because they will most likely change in the future and the bug in the question won't be reproducible anymore (as you've demonstrated here). Provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and embed it in the question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into your repo, and the revelant code is this, in `player.py`:

```
def move_player(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Player movement
        if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_d):
                self.player_acc = PLAYER_ACC

            if (event.key == pygame.K_a):
                self.player_acc = -PLAYER_ACC

        if (event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
            if (event.key == pygame.K_d):
                self.player_acc = 0

            if (event.key == pygame.K_a):
                self.player_acc = 0
```

Think about what happens in your main loop:

```
while g.running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            g.running = False
    g.run(Player_1)
```

You get all events from the event queue, clearing it, and check for `QUIT`.

Then you call `g.run`, which will call `self.update_game`, which will call `Player.move_player`, which will again get all events from the event queue and clear it.

So when the `QUIT` event is in the event queue at the moment `pygame.event.get()` is called inside `Player.move_player`, it is practically lost, since you don't handle it in this `for` loop. When `pygame.event.get()` is then called again in `main`, the `QUIT` event is no longer in the queue (because calling `event.get` clears the queue).

Basically, you should call 'event.get' only once per main loop iteration (the same is true for `pygame.display.flip`/`pygame.display.update`).

Maybe change the loop in `main` to something like this:

```
while g.running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        g.handle(event, Player_1)
    g.run(Player_1)
```

add this to `Game`:

```
def handle(self, event, player_1):
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        self.running = False
    else:
        player_1.handle(event)
```

and this to `Player`:

```
def handle(self, event):
    # Player movement
    if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
        if (event.key == pygame.K_d):
            self.player_acc = PLAYER_ACC

        if (event.key == pygame.K_a):
            self.player_acc = -PLAYER_ACC

    if (event.type == pygame.KEYUP):
        if (event.key == pygame.K_d):
            self.player_acc = 0

        if (event.key == pygame.K_a):
            self.player_acc = 0
```

and remove `Player.move_player`

Comment: I changed that but it gave this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/ScrewAround/100DaysOfCodeProject1/main.py", line 103, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/ScrewAround/100DaysOfCodeProject1/main.py", line 98, in main
    g.run(Player_1)
  File "C:/ScrewAround/100DaysOfCodeProject1/main.py", line 58, in run
    self.update_game(player_1)
  File "C:/ScrewAround/100DaysOfCodeProject1/main.py", line 50, in update_game
    Player.handle(player_1)
TypeError: handle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Comment: remove `Player.handle(player_1)` from `update_game`. Look at the code in my answer. The main loop calls `g.handle(event, Player_1)`, and `Game.handle` calls `player_1.handle(event)`.

Comment: But then the sprite doesn't move anymore.

Comment: @Maartenww Yeah, the line `if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):` should also be removed from the main loop. My bad. I changed the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand the answer now. 
I appreciate your efforts.@sloth

Answer (score 1):

I expect the loop does run, but you've hit a case of type mismatch not being reported.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event == pygame.QUIT:
```

`event` will be a [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object. The `QUIT` value you're checking against is a value that might appear in the `event.type` attribute. Since no event is the integer value `QUIT`, all events are being ignored. You might want to add an `else` clause to diagnose which events are received but not handled.

Comment: I added an else statement and made it print the event. What I found out
is that it runs the loop very irregularly. In other words it only works if you click the x button at a specific time which is impossible to time.

Comment: I believe sloth found the reason for that (I hadn't dug through the source repo as thoroughly).

Comment: @YannVernier your answer is also valid, because the code in the question clearly has the bug you describe in your answer; but it's correct in the github repo.